# How to remove TextInputLayout drawable padding?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I am using `ExitText` inside `TextInputLayout` and have enable ``

```
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
```

And getting `Toggle` view as below

[image]

I want to remove Right Padding of the `toggle` but somehow not able to. 
I have all set everything `0dp`, but no success.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:drawablePadding="0dp"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

There are some naive solutions like setting negative margin, but as I don't know the size of padding I can't do that either. Any suggestion?

Comment: show us the full xml, which include the `toggleButton`.

Comment: Sorry for lack of that line. Just added. Nothing special, I just added `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` in my `TextInputLayout`

Comment: See also https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/366.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                android:id="@+id/tilPassword"
                                style="@style/text_input_layout_style"
                                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                                    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                                    style="@style/text_input_edit_text_without_border_style"
                                    android:contentDescription="Password"
                                    android:maxLength="@integer/pass_max"
                                    android:digits="@string/textPasswordDigits"
                                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/drawable_ic_eyes"
                                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_small"
                                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                                    android:hint="@string/label_password"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (left drawable) https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/366 works.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:startIconMinSize="10dp"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_search">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="-10dp" /> <!-- Negative value here -->

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

---

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ... >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```